# SQL MINUS result to include other columns in result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I get the records I need with the below select statement, which is the CAR_COLOR from the CARS_PRIMARY table that don't exist in the CAR_SECONDARY table (also has CAR_COLOR column), but how do I now include the other matching columns for the results, so it retuns the additional columns associated with the results of the select statement below

```
SELECT CAR_COLOR
FROM CARS_PRIMARY
MINUS
SELECT CAR_COLOR
FROM CARS_SECONDARY
```

Currently the results
are

```
PINK
BLUE
GREEN
```

I need

```
PINK   SUV    4DOOR      
BLUE   CAR    2DOOR
GREEN  TRUCK  2DOOR
```

Comment: Sql server has MINUS?I think you want EXCEPT.

Comment: I'll see if that works and mark it as answered if it returns the selected results.

Comment: @Mihai I have MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and MINUS does work.

Comment: `MINUS` would parse as an *alias*, not any kind of *operation*.

Comment: Tested on sql server 2012,doesnt work.

Comment: The question is not clear.  You have to tell us where the car type and number of doors come from.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk I stated in the question "How do I now include the other matching columns for the results, so it retuns the additional columns associated with the results of the select statement below."

Comment: @Mihai I'm not sure what to tell you I'm running MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2 and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `NOT IN` instead of a `MINUS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM cars_primary
WHERE car_color NOT IN
    (SELECT car_color
    FROM cars_secondary)
```

or alternatively

```
SELECT *
FROM cars_primary
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT NULL
    FROM cars_secondary
    WHERE cars_secondary.car_color = cars_primary.car_color)
```

Comment: You should use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` as the latter doesn't necessarily handle `NULLS` correctly. It's also [faster](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Comment: How would I re-write select statement with 'NOT EXISTS'

Comment: @ConfusedDeer added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### `MINUS` / `EXCEPT`

```
SELECT *
FROM CARS_PRIMARY
WHERE CAR_COLOR IN (
   SELECT CAR_COLOR
   FROM CARS_PRIMARY
   EXCEPT
   SELECT CAR_COLOR
   FROM CARS_SECONDARY
);
```

#### Explanation:

We first get a set of all colors in `CARS_PRIMARY` but not in `CARS_SECONDARY` and then select all columns from `CARS_PRIMARY` that have that color.

<sup>I used `EXCEPT`, but if `MINUS` works, you can use that.</sup>

---

### `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT CP.*
FROM CARS_PRIMARY CP
LEFT JOIN CARS_SECONDARY CS 
    ON (CP.CAR_COLOR = CS.CAR_COLOR)
WHERE CS.CAR_COLOR IS NULL;
```

#### Explanation:

We do on outer join from `CARS_PRIMARY` to `CARS_SECONDARY` on the color and then discard all rows that have values from `CARS_SECONDARY`.

---

### `NOT IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM CARS_PRIMARY
WHERE CAR_COLOR NOT IN (
   SELECT CAR_COLOR
   FROM CARS_SECONDARY
);
```

#### Explanation

We select all columns from `CARS_PRIMARY` where the color is not in the set of colors from `CARS_SECONDARY`.

---

### `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM CARS_PRIMARY CP
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM CARS_SECONDARY CS
   WHERE CS.CAR_COLOR = CP.CAR_COLOR
);
```

#### Explanation

We select all columns from `CARS_PRIMARY` where the color does not exist in `CARS_SECONDARY`.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: @ConfusedDeer I had a couple of table names wrong, can you please try again? Also, I used `EXCEPT`; please substitute `MINUS` if that works for you.

Comment: @D Stanley answer already worked after I tried yours, so I guess I have to give him the answer, but I will try to see if that works as well.